# How to modify case with select to return additional value from table?

Tags: sql, oracle

This query :

```
   SELECT T.DID  , (CASE
          WHEN A.AMT >= 150 AND
               T.DVAL LIKE '%ID%' THEN
           '1'
          ELSE
           '0'
        END Q_A)
FROM PTD T
JOIN CUST.ACT A ON T.DID = A.DID
WHERE T.DID IN (1111 , 2222)
```

returns :

```
1
0
```

I'm attempting to modify this query such that `DID` is also returned for the given query. In other words modify the query to return :

```
1111 , 1
2222 , 0
```

Here is my attempt :

```
     SELECT T.DID  , (CASE
          WHEN A.AMT >= 150 AND
               T.DVAL LIKE '%ID%' THEN
           '1'
          ELSE
           '0'
        END Q_A)
FROM PTD T
JOIN CUST.ACT A ON T.DID = A.DID
WHERE T.DID IN (1111 , 2222)
```

But I receive error :

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

How to update query in order to return `DID` value from table ?

Comment: Your original query *does* return `T.DID`.

Comment: The problem is that the column alias Q_A doesn't belong inside the parentheses. But why do you want parentheses around your `CASE` expression at all? Just remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second query the closing paren is misplaced.  It needs to go after the `END` so it surrounds the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT T.DID,
       (CASE WHEN A.AMT >= 150 AND T.DVAL LIKE '%ID%'
            THEN '1' ELSE '0'
       END) AS Q_A
FROM PTD T JOIN
     CUST.ACT A
     ON T.DID = A.DID
WHERE T.DID IN (1111, 2222)
```

Comment: If so, shouldn't the question be closed as a typo?